# How to parse HTML in PHP?

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I know we can use [PHP DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to parse HTML using PHP. I found a lot of questions here on Stack Overflow too. But I have a specific requirement. I have an HTML content like below

```
<p class="Heading1-P">
    <span class="Heading1-H">Chapter 1</span>
</p>
<p class="Normal-P">
    <span class="Normal-H">This is chapter 1</span>
</p>
<p class="Heading1-P">
    <span class="Heading1-H">Chapter 2</span>
</p>
<p class="Normal-P">
    <span class="Normal-H">This is chapter 2</span>
</p>
<p class="Heading1-P">
    <span class="Heading1-H">Chapter 3</span>
</p>
<p class="Normal-P">
    <span class="Normal-H">This is chapter 3</span>
</p>
```

I want to parse the above HTML and save the content into two different arrays like:

`$heading` and `$content`

```
$heading = array('Chapter 1','Chapter 2','Chapter 3');
$content = array('This is chapter 1','This is chapter 2','This is chapter 3');
```

I can achieve this simply using jQuery. But I am not sure, if that's the right way.
It would be great if someone can point me to the right direction.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use jquery as its structure is simple.

Comment: @Susheel: HTML content will be much bigger as it is the output after parsing `docx` files

Comment: You could use regular expressions if you don't like to go for PHP DOM.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer [do not use regular expressions to parse html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @blessed for bigger dom use php simple dom parser

Comment: @blessed, I have added solution at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18349663/749232

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try to look at [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

It has brilliant syntax similar to jQuery so you can easily select any element you want by ID or class

```
// include/require the simple html dom parser file

$html_string = '
    <p class="Heading1-P">
        <span class="Heading1-H">Chapter 1</span>
    </p>
    <p class="Normal-P">
        <span class="Normal-H">This is chapter 1</span>
    </p>
    <p class="Heading1-P">
        <span class="Heading1-H">Chapter 2</span>
    </p>
    <p class="Normal-P">
        <span class="Normal-H">This is chapter 2</span>
    </p>
    <p class="Heading1-P">
        <span class="Heading1-H">Chapter 3</span>
    </p>
    <p class="Normal-P">
        <span class="Normal-H">This is chapter 3</span>
    </p>';
$html = str_get_html($html_string);
foreach($html->find('span') as $element) {
    if ($element->class === 'Heading1-H') {
        $heading[] = $element->innertext;
    }else if($element->class === 'Normal-H') {
        $content[] = $element->innertext;
    }
}
```

Comment: !!NOTICE!! not using "->innertext" leads to memory leaks.

Comment: This is a much easier option and produces more readable code compared to using DomDocument.

Comment: Is there an option to install that with composer?

Comment: Composer install [is now possible](https://sourceforge.net/p/simplehtmldom/news/2019/10/composer-package/): `composer require simplehtmldom/simlehtmldom dev-master` and `use simplehtmldom\HtmlWeb;`

Comment: @luckydonald there is a typo in your comment. missing the "p" in the second "simple" in the composer require command

Comment: @Philip yeah, that typo is in the [linked official source](https://sourceforge.net/p/simplehtmldom/news/2019/10/composer-package/). The corrected version would then be like this:   `composer require simplehtmldom/simplehtmldom dev-master` and `use simplehtmldom\HtmlWeb;`

Answer (score 30):

I have used domdocument and domxpath to get the solution, you can find it at:

```
<?php
$dom = new DomDocument();
$test='<p class="Heading1-P">
    <span class="Heading1-H">Chapter 1</span>
</p>
<p class="Normal-P">
    <span class="Normal-H">This is chapter 1</span>
</p>
<p class="Heading1-P">
    <span class="Heading1-H">Chapter 2</span>
</p>
<p class="Normal-P">
    <span class="Normal-H">This is chapter 2</span>
</p>
<p class="Heading1-P">
    <span class="Heading1-H">Chapter 3</span>
</p>
<p class="Normal-P">
    <span class="Normal-H">This is chapter 3</span>
</p>';

$dom->loadHTML($test);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
    $heading=parseToArray($xpath,'Heading1-H');
    $content=parseToArray($xpath,'Normal-H');

var_dump($heading);
echo "<br/>";
var_dump($content);
echo "<br/>";

function parseToArray($xpath,$class)
{
    $xpathquery="//span[@class='".$class."']";
    $elements = $xpath->query($xpathquery);

    if (!is_null($elements)) {  
        $resultarray=array();
        foreach ($elements as $element) {
            $nodes = $element->childNodes;
            foreach ($nodes as $node) {
              $resultarray[] = $node->nodeValue;
            }
        }
        return $resultarray;
    }
}
```

**Live result:** http://saji89.codepad.org/2TyOAibZ

Comment: I've found this link to be very useful to learn the XPATH.query syntax: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

Answer (score 10):

Here's an alternative way to parse the html using [`DiDOM`](https://github.com/Imangazaliev/DiDOM) which offers significantly [better performance](https://github.com/Imangazaliev/DiDOM/wiki/Comparison-with-other-parsers-(1.0)) in terms of speed and memory footprint.

```sh
composer require imangazaliev/didom
```

```php
<?php

use DiDom\Document;

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$html = <<<HTML
<p class="Heading1-P">
    <span class="Heading1-H">Chapter 1</span>
</p>
<p class="Normal-P">
    <span class="Normal-H">This is chapter 1</span>
</p>
<p class="Heading1-P">
    <span class="Heading1-H">Chapter 2</span>
</p>
<p class="Normal-P">
    <span class="Normal-H">This is chapter 2</span>
</p>
<p class="Heading1-P">
    <span class="Heading1-H">Chapter 3</span>
</p>
<p class="Normal-P">
    <span class="Normal-H">This is chapter 3</span>
</p>
HTML;

$document = new Document($html);

// find chapter headings
$elements = $document->find('.Heading1-H');

$headings = [];

foreach ($elements as $element) {
    $headings[] = $element->text();
}

// find chapter texts
$elements = $document->find('.Normal-H');

$chapters = [];

foreach ($elements as $element) {
    $chapters[] = $element->text();
}

echo("Headings\n");

foreach ($headings as $heading) {
    echo("- {$heading}\n");
}

echo("Chapter texts\n");

foreach ($chapters as $chapter) {
    echo("- {$chapter}\n");
}
```

Comment: Love it when you find an old question on SO with a really good modern answer.  That DOM parser is excellent, cheers.

Answer (score 5):

One option for you is to use DOMDocument and DOMXPath. They do require a bit of a curve to learn, but once you do, you will be pretty happy with what you can achieve.

Read the following in php.net

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php

Hope this helps.

Comment: This has problem with broken html

Comment: dont. use. phps. dom. This answer is old. PHPs Dom doesn't get along with 2020+ HTML

Answer (score -12):

// Create DOM from URL or file

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
```

// Find all images

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
   echo $element->src . '<br>';
```

// Find all links

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
   echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Comment: file_get_html ?? Is that a PHP function ?

Comment: file_get_content is right. he has copy past from php simple dom website