# Get the content from HTML tags

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get the content from the html tags

```
function get_model($html){
  return preg_match('!<b>Model:</b>(.*?)<br>!i', $html, $matches) ? $matches[1] : '';
}
```

But, it returns "" string.
The entire html code looks like:

```
<div class="prodInfo">


    <div class="prodOptions">
        <div class="redBtn">
            <a href="#" class="minusCart">-</a>
            <input type="text" class="tnyTxt" value="1" name="quantity"/>
            <a href="#" class="plusCart">+</a>
        </div>
        <br/>



        <a href="/0-30cb9a-adjustable-pan-connector-p-mw555"
           onclick="addToCart(139, $('.tnyTxt').val() ); return false;" class="redBtn"
           id="button-cart">Add to Cart</a>
    </div>

<p>
    <b>Our Price: <span class="price">£5.55</span></b><br/>

            <span class="grey">
                  (Exc. 20% VAT)<br/>
                  (£6.66 Inc. VAT)
                </span>
    </p>

<p>
    <b>Model:</b>  MW555<br/>
    <b>Availability:</b>   2 - 3 Days</p>


</div>
```

I'm not quite understand why is this? even if I write `preg_match('!<b>Model:</b>)` it also return empty result. Could you help me please?

Comment: you should use an HTML parser here instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this **[PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)**.
This question have also duplicate :-

1. [How parse HTML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349130/how-parse-html-in-php)

Comment: Thanks! It is realy easy to use!! It save me a lot of time, instead using regular expressions)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer You to use [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) for this job.