# How to extract Tag Value from PHP not Tag code?

Tags: php

I need to get the 4th H4 Tag Value
HTML Code looks like below :

```
                  <div class="col-md-6 mb-6 mb-md-3">
                    <h3 class="mb-3">testing 1</h5>
                    <h4 class="mb-0 abcd defg hikjk lmnop">Not needed this Value</h4>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-6 mb-6 mb-md-3">
                    <h3 class="mb-3">testing 2 </h5>
                    <h4 class="mb-0 abcd defg hikjk lmnop">Not needed this Value</h4>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-6 mb-6 mb-md-3">
                    <h3 class="mb-3">testing 3</h5>
                    <h4 class="mb-0 abcd defg hikjk lmnop">Not needed this Value</h4>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-6 mb-6 mb-md-3">
                    <h3 class="mb-3">testing</h5>
                    <h4 class="mb-0 abcd defg hikjk lmnop">**Needed this Value only**</h4>
                  </div>
```

I really appreciate is somebody can help.

Below what I am looking for :

Got HTML from CURL request

Than,

```
    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load($content);
```

$html->find('h4') as $h4)

$value = $h4->???????;   --> what should be the value ??

Comment: Try to use JS DOM method especially selector

Comment: Have you done any research at all and made an attempt?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349130/how-to-parse-html-in-php

Comment: Ok, below is the context i am looking for :  $html = new simple_html_dom();
  $html->load($content);      $html->find('h1') as $myLink   $h1 = $myLink-> ???????;    Please let me know the value

Comment: Have you reviewed [the documentation](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual_api.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a builtin DOM parser, you don't need a third-party library for a simple lookup:

```
<?php

$input = '<div class="col-md-6 mb-6 mb-md-3">
    <h3 class="mb-3">testing 1</h5>
    <h4 class="mb-0 abcd defg hikjk lmnop">Not needed this Value</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 mb-6 mb-md-3">
    <h3 class="mb-3">testing 2 </h5>
    <h4 class="mb-0 abcd defg hikjk lmnop">Not needed this Value</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 mb-6 mb-md-3">
    <h3 class="mb-3">testing 3</h5>
    <h4 class="mb-0 abcd defg hikjk lmnop">Not needed this Value</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 mb-6 mb-md-3">
    <h3 class="mb-3">testing</h5>
    <h4 class="mb-0 abcd defg hikjk lmnop">**Needed this Value only**</h4>
  </div>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($input);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

var_dump($dom->getElementsByTagName('h4')[3]->nodeValue);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/3p9Ba) / [Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php)