# PHP, Extract data between HTML Tags that have same name

Tags: php, html, regex, dom, extract

I have this HTML page that I want to extract the data between its Tags.

```
<div>
    <h2>Google</h2>
    <a href="google.com/about">Google is search engine</a>
    <a href="google.com">www.google.com</a>
</div>
<div>
    <h2>Amazon</h2>
    <a href="amazon.com/about">Amazon is shopping cart</a>
    <a href="amazon.com">www.amazon.com</a>
</div>
<div>
    <h2>Yahoo</h2>
    <a href="yahoo.com/about">Yahoo is websites directory</a>
    <a href="yahoo.com">www.yahoo.com</a>
</div>
```

And I want to use this pure PHP code:

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents("demo.html");
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a'); 
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h2');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue."<br>";
} ?>
```

How can extract the data to be like this:

```
Google      Google is search engine     www.google.com
Amazon      Amazon is shopping cart     www.yahoo.com
Yahoo       Yahho is websites directory www.yahoo.com
```

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349130/how-to-parse-html-in-php

Comment: Does the HTML only contain the `<div>` elements, it's easier to start from there if possible.

Comment: @rootkonda There is no Div ID or Class,  just TagName duplicated one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can identify that particular block of data as this assumes that you are just looking at each `<div>` tag and the same contents for each one.

It just uses `getElementsByTagName()` at the various levels to fetch the data, with the `<a>` tags, it assumes the 2 tags so uses `[0]` and `[1]` to get the data from each.

```
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->getElementsByTagName('h2')[0]->nodeValue."/";
    $a = $node->getElementsByTagName('a');
    echo $a[0]->nodeValue."/";
    echo $a[1]->nodeValue."<br>";
}
```

which with the sample gives...

```
Google/Google is search engine/www.google.com<br>
Amazon/Amazon is shopping cart/www.amazon.com<br>
Yahoo/Yahoo is websites directory/www.yahoo.com<br>
```

Comment: it works with these errors: 'Notice: Trying to get property of non-objec' and this one 'Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag header invalid in Entity'

Comment: For the Entity issue, you could add `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` before `$dom->loadHTML($html);`. See if this helps.