# Replace word in text between Tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i know that there are many similar question but none have what im looking for, i need to replace a word from a text between tags  but the problem is that is not having in account spaces or other wors so it doesnt match,

I tried adding before comma the /b but is not working.

Code Example:

```
$content= preg_replace('@(?<=<p>)'.$value->data['target'].'(?=.*</p>)@', $value->data['string'], $content);
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at DomDocument here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349130/ddg#18349663

Comment: I checked, im now able to match the word if there are charecters at fron of the works i added "(?=.*</p>)@" in the end of pattern, but now i cant make it detec if there are charecters behind the word im trying to match,.

Comment: Please add context to the question, e.g. input string and expected output string. Likely the answer is to use a parser, not regex.

Comment: Which comma? Sure you don't want to use [`preg_quote()`](https://www.php.net/preg_quote) for your "target"? Have you thought about potential HTML entities?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find the text between tags and replace it. You can try the following code:

```
function replace_content_between_tags(string $content, string $tagname, string $searchStr, string $replaceWith)
{
   $pattern = "#<\s*?$tagname\b[^>]*>(.*?)</$tagname\b[^>]*>#s";
   preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches);

   foreach($matches[1] as $key => $match) {
    
     if(strpos($match, $searchStr) !== false) {
        $replaceContent = '<' . $tagname . '>' . $match . '</' . $tagname . '>';
        $content = str_replace($replaceContent, $replaceWith, $content);
        break ;
     }
   }
            
   return $content;
    
}

$new_content = replace_content_between_tags($content, 'p', $value->data['target'], $value->data['string']);
```

Comment: Is messing with the content i have, is replacing and removing some paragraps

Comment: This can be pretty dangerous if nested content. `str_replace` usage also is incorrect.

Comment: @Pedro i updated my answer now. Let me know if it works