# extracting only image src, not other 'src' tags in html with php

Tags: php, html, preg-match

I've been able to use preg_match on getting the src of any image tags, but I only really need the src of images with class 'wp-post-image' in this case. However, this code is returning nothing for me

```
$pattern = '<img(?:[^>]+src="(.+?)"[^>]+(?:id|class)="image"|[^>]+(?:id|class)="wp-post-image"[^>]+src="(.+?)")
';
preg_match($pattern,$results[$k]['description'], $matches);
$results[$k]['image'] = $matches[0];
print_r($results[$k]['image']);
```

The old version returns all image matches which includes 4 that have the class I'm looking for so maybe my syntax is just wrong?

old version that returned all images:

```
$pattern = '%<img.*?src=["\'](.*?)["\'].*?/>%i';
                        preg_match($pattern,$results[$k]['description'], $matches);
                        $src = $matches[0];
                         //print_r($src);
```

Comment: In my opinion, you better use the [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) API and its methods `loadHtml()` and `getElementByTagName()` for this kind of job.

Comment: Although parsing HTML using RegEx is not wrong, it will sometimes/often/always eventually lead to additional edge cases. [Obligatory link here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/231316). I agree with @rugolinifr, PHP has several built-in (or at least commonly installed) [HTML parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18349154/231316) that you can use in a more declarative way.

Comment: @rugolinifr I'll look into DOMDocument now. Is it just built-in? I'm using PHP7 through Xenforo

Answer (score 0):

1. Asking to parse HTML with regex on SO will get you flamed.  Not without reason, but flamed nonetheless.
2. If you insist on using regex (which, if for nothing else, is good practice), I suggest using a regex sandbox to test out patterns on sample text.  One I use is https://regex101.com/ .
3. The old version (which you say worked) is looking for either single or double quotes around the `src` attribute.  The new version is only looking for double quotes, which is possibly why it's failing.
4. Rather than trying to write a more complicated regex, it may be easier to use your old regex -- which grabs all the image links -- along with an expanded capture, and then look through the captured links to sort out the ones you need:

`$pattern = '%(<img.*?src=["\'].*?["\'].*?/>)%i';`