# getting img element by class name is returning too many results

Tags: php, html

I'm using this code for a reg ex in order to get every img element that has the class 'wp-post-image' but it's getting images that don't have that tag just because they're close by:

```
$results = 'img src="https://api.follow.it" border=0 width="1" height="1"> <img width="150" height="150" src="https://www.sitefeed.com/testImage.jpg" class="webfeedsFeaturedVisual wp-post-image"<p>This is a test for RSS feeds</p>';
$pattern = '/<img.+?class=".*?wp-post-image.*?"/';
preg_match($pattern, $results, $classMatches);
dump($classMatches);
```

with that HTML snippet, I'm getting both image elements in my dump.

How can I match ONLY the image with the matching class name?

Comment: I'd recommend the same thing that we said for your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71710767/231316), you are much better off using an HTML-aware parser

Comment: @ChrisHaas ah, I thought I had left another comment there: I tried using DOMdocument but it broke mypage (this is in a xenforo site) so I instead made it to where I would match only the image needed and use an if statement to get the src of that match, but even that left me with a bit of an issue here. I'll see if I can figure out a different HTML parser for my setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following function:

```
function get_string_between(string $str, string $tagName, string $findClass = '')
{
   $tags = explode('<', $str);
              
   $classMatches = '';
              
   foreach ($tags as $tag) {
     if (strpos($tag, $tagName) !== false && strpos($tag, $findClass) !== false ) {
        $tag = str_replace('>', '', $tag);
        $classMatches .= '<' . $tag . '>';
     }
   }
    
   return $classMatches;

}

$classMatches = get_string_between($results, 'img', 'wp-post-image');
```